# place a linearLayout in center of a wrap_content relativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a listView, and view of each item of the list should be like this (a background image and group name) :

[image: list_item]

but when i set layout_centerInParent="true" to linearLayout, it placed in center of screen(not in center of image).like this :

[image]

and there is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#444">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/test"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/linear_category_name"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp">
        <ir.dbasoft.test.myobject.MyTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Gold"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can i place linearLayout in center of relaytiveLayout ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your scenario, I think it's a lot easier to use FrameLayout instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/gold_image"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/white_border"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I've tested this and it looked exactly like what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#444">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/test/>

    <ir.dbasoft.test.myobject.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Gold"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/test"/>

    <ir.dbasoft.test.myobject.MyTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Gold"/>
```